# QtCore could not be found by catkin_make a SpotMicro(robot-dog)

Tags: server, raspberrypi, qt5, ros

Anyone met a problem when compiling a spot micro there is an error "reported QT_INSTALL_LIBS as "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu" but qtcore could not be found there. QT is NOT installed correctly for the target build environment. Anyone has a suggestion what can I do to solve it?

And if I am writing the export path for qtcore I get an error it can not find a package configuration file provided be "sensor_msgs" but if I am writing a path for sensor_msgs it's giving me the first error.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 pi, ros noetic and qt5

Comment: Compiling : Build requirements → Libraries must be (lib)name-dev. ... You could be missing `qtbase5-dev`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/qt5-default

Comment: Adding qtbase5-dev didn't resolved this issue.